# Include Angular dist folder in msbuild output

Tags: angular, jenkins, webpack, msbuild

I have one Mvc Project in which I have my Angualar2 app which is bundled by webpack.so when I perform **npm run build:prod** on my root the dist folder gets generated.After that when I perform **msbuild** on the project dist folder is not included in the project output as it's not included in the project.Is there anyway with which I can include the dist folder in my build output folder without including in project as this is needed for Jenkins Auto deployment.Any approach suggestion is highly appreciable.

Comment: You can set `outDir` to wherever you want in `.angular-cli.json`.
Like `outDir: "../msbuild/some-project/out-folder"`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner In most ASP .Net MVC projects with Angular, Angular application will be within a sub-folder (not in project root). So that would require angular CLIS **ng build** to access folder path out side the CLI's root. Not sure if outDir could direct to random folders outside its scope

Comment: @DavidChelliah yeah it can. I've done something similar in Java application. You can give any file path you want within file system.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a separate task in Jenkins, as that would require you to hardcode From (Source checked-out) path and To (Publish package location) path.

So easier & best way would be the following one,

You simply create your custom tasks & hook that to the already available MSBuild pipeline Targets.

To include all files that are not part of .csproject (i.e., not included in .csproj) during publish packaging

1) Hook to CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackage action and point it to custom target defined for copying Angular files - *CollectAngularFiles*

```
<CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CollectAngularFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
</CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
```

2) Define your targets [`ng\dist` - was my angular *output/dist* folder]

```
<Target Name="CollectAngularFiles">
<ItemGroup>
  <GeneratedScripts Include="ng\dist\**\*" />
  <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(GeneratedScripts.Identity)">
    <DestinationRelativePath>ng\dist\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
  </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
</ItemGroup>
```

For more clear implementation guide, you can check following blog post
https://davidsekar.com/angular/include-angular-generated-files-in-msbuild-package